# How to make the placeholder disappear when I type something in the div?

Tags: jquery, html, placeholder

The Jquery

```
 function placehold(id,placeholder) // id of element and placeholder text
{
    $("#"+id).text(placeholder); //initialize form field

}
    $(document).ready(function() {


       document.getElementById("editable").addEventListener("input", function() {

         if ($(this).text()==(""))
        {
           placehold('editable','Please enter a name');
        }

       }, false);

        var originaltext = $('#editable').text();

}
```

The HTML

```
<div id="editable" contentEditable="true"><?php 

    if(!empty($row['Name']))
    {
        echo $row['Name'];

    }
    else
    {

    echo "Please enter a name";
    }
        ?>
     </div>
```

if my "editable" is empty, the placeholder "please enter a name" would appear

When I type in the textbox, The placeholder exist together with my text

how can I make the placeholder gone when I try to type inside my DIV?

Comment: why r u using placeholder text like that? use placeholder attribute instead..

Comment: @Rinku divs have no placeholder attribute, and I guess he wants to style elements within the div so he can't use a text-box or input-field.

Comment: yes exactly...there is no placeholder attribute, so I can only do it in a hard way

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution:

**// html code**

```
<div id="editable" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

**// Java script code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var newText, originaltext = '';

    $('#editable').html(function () {        
        if ($.trim($(this).html()) == "") {
            placehold('editable', 'Please enter a name');
            originaltext = $.trim($('#editable').html());
        }
    });
    $('#editable').click(function () {        
        if ($.trim($(this).html()) == originaltext) {
            placehold('editable', '');
        } else {
            placehold('editable', newText);
        }
    });
    $('#editable').blur(function () {         
        newText = $('#editable').html();               
        if ($.trim($(this).html()) != originaltext && $.trim($(this).html()) !='') {            
            placehold('editable', newText);
        } else {
            placehold('editable', originaltext);
        }
    });

});
function placehold(id, placeholder) {
    $("#" + id).html(placeholder);
}
```

**Demo**

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/YBAMC/)

Comment: Your text disappears when clicking on the element, while placeholders stick around until the user starts typing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [this Text-Box Hints Plugin](http://remysharp.com/2007/01/25/jquery-tutorial-text-box-hints/).

It works on divs with contenteditable too.

Here is a [Demo](http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/input_hint.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and easy example to get you started.

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='in' value='Enter Something...'>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#in').bind({
    click : function() {
        $(this).css('color','#ccc');
    },
    focusout : function() {
        $(this).css('color','#000');
    },
    keydown : function() {
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).css('color','#000');
        $(this).unbind('keydown');
        $(this).unbind('click');
    },
});
```

Good luck

Comment: I am using DIV, not textbox

Answer (score 0):

This code will run exactly as a normal placeholder:

- The text is grey when it's the placeholder's text
- The placeholder text will disappear when you start typing
- When the text is empty, the placeholder will be restored
- On focusing when the placeholder is displayed, the cursor moves to the beginning

**FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/WyGVA/5/

```
<div id="editable" contentEditable="true" tabindex="0">Please enter a name</div>
```

Notice the `tabindex`, this is added so users with Firefox will be able to trigger `keydown` and `keyup` events.

This is all the javascript, using the jQuery library:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#editable').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            text = $.trim($this.text().toLowerCase());

        // Force cursor at the beginning
        if (text === 'please enter a name') {
            $this.text('');
            $this.focus();
            $this.text('Please enter a name');
        }
    });

    $('#editable').keydown(function (event) {
        var $this = $(this),
            text = $.trim($this.text().toLowerCase());

        if (text === 'please enter a name') {
            $this.text('');
            $this.css('color', 'black');
        }
    });
    $('#editable').keyup(function (event) {
        var $this = $(this),
            text = $.trim($this.text().toLowerCase());

        if (text === '') {
            $this.text('Please enter a name');
            $this.css('color', 'grey');
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit**: Updated to move the cursor at the beginning when focusing on the div.
This code could be cleaner by saving the placeholder somewhere, but it's mostly to help you get further on. Good luck!

Comment: The downfall of this code is that it doesn't remove placeholder on focus but on keydown which enables you to place the caret in the middle of the placeholder which can be very confusing.